# Is there some nomenclature to get the remainder of a value?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to write a formula where I can say that I have to get the remainder of a division by 4.

$y = \mathbf{remainder}(x\div4)$

Is there any math nomenclature I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say $y=x\pmod 4$

See [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: That would be less ambiguously written as $\ y = (x\ {\rm mod}\ 4),\ $ which avoids it being misinterpreted as $\ y\equiv x\pmod 4.$

Comment: @KeyIdeas Is that notation even used? I've never seen it.

Comment: $ x\ {\rm mod}\ m\ $ is very widely used for the remainder function. But $\ x\ ({\rm mod}\ m)\ $ often denotes the equivalence class $\ x + m\,\Bbb Z,\,$ not the remainder (though, in some contexts, they may denote the same object).

Comment: @KeyIdeas I understand all those subtleties, I just never saw that notation before. Feel free to post your own answer and I'll delete mine. However I get the feeling that is sufficient for the OP.

Comment: @KeyIdeas Oops, can't delete it now. The OP accepted this answer.

Answer (score 2):

For integer  $x$, put $\,y\,$ equal to $\;\bf x \;\text{mod}\; 4\;$. The "mod" operator will return the remainder when $x$ is divided by $4$.

See, for example: [remainders: Modular Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Remainders)

Note: In computer programming, this is often denoted $\;x\, \%\, 4$, where $x$ is an integer.

Comment: Nice when you add links +1